# Finding the median based on conditions to fill in missing values

Tags: pandas, numpy

I have a dataframe containing state, county, year, and hpi (housing price index). There are missing values in the hpi column. From what is done to fill in those values is taking the median of the hpi values and filling the missing values with that median.

What I want to do instead is find the median based on the year, state, and county name and for values that are missing fill it in with the median. To me that seems a bit more robust than taking the median of the entire dataset.

Here is a sample of the data I have:

[image]

Thus the median is 184.02 and I would fill in those empty values with it.

This is what I have tried in Python:

```
def get_median(year, state, county):
    for years in data['Year']:
        for states in data['state']:
            for counties in data['County_name']:
                if years == year and states == state and counties == county:
                    return np.median(data['hpi'])
print(get_median(2012, 'Alaska', 'Anchorage Municipality'))
```

Since my data is much much larger than the sample provided the function above takes quite awhile to run and is O(n^3) in time complexity so not so good. Is there a more pythonic way of doing this that is much faster?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `groupby`:

```
medians = df.groupby(['year','state','County_name'])['hpi'].transform('median')

df['hpi'] = df['hpi'].fillna(medians)
```

If there are some county without any data:

```
medians = (df.groupby(['year', 'state', 'County_name'])['hpi']
             .transform(lambda x: x.median() if x.notnull().any() else np.nan)
          )
```

Comment: I am getting this error: DataError: No numeric types to aggregate

Comment: Make sure that your `hpi` column is numeric. If it already is, there might be some county that does not have any data.

Comment: Yea the data['hpi'] column is of floating type. Okay for the counties that do not have any idea is there a way of skipping those in your code?

Answer (score 0):

You can get the median for each group with this code, you can use the median that comes with pandas as it ignores NaNs by default:

```
data_median = data.groupby(['Year','state','County_name']).agg({'col1':'median'}).reset_index().rename(columns={'col1':'median_hpi'})
```

Note I rename the column to make the next step easier. There are probably cleaner ways to do that but this is the quick way I usually use.

Once you have a dataframe with the medians you can join that back to the original and coalesce/combine_first() to get the median if hpi is null.

```
data = data.merge(data_median, on = ['Year','state','County_name'])
data['filled_hpi'] = data.hpa.combine_first(data.median_hpi)
```

That should do the trick much quicker.